# SBT multiproject can't locate logback extension

Tags: scala, sbt, logback, sbt-assembly

I have a multi project SBT build where the `common` project contains a logback related extension, while logback.xml is placed in a global resource folder.

I have a structure as below, but when running the application (`App`) it is not applying `LogbackCompositeConverterEx`.

How do I get the logback CompositeConverter to affect depending projects at runtime?

```
build.sbt

|- Common
|-- src
|--- main
|---- scala
|----- LogbackCompositeConverterEx.scala // Does not seem to be applied
|---- resources

|- Feature
|-- src
|--- main
|---- scala
|---- resources

|- App
|-- src
|--- main
|---- scala
|---- resources
|----- logback.xml // Can this be in common?
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, you can move the logback.xml in the common, resources folder. But I'm not sure that will fix the issue. Is there a way to share the project privately, or at least the build.sbt, to be able to check how you have defined the dependencies and aggregation of submodules?